# pandas dataframe imported CSV with all rows in one column. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've imported a CSV into python in with this function:

```
def import_csv(path):

    return pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-16')


df = import_csv('path to CSV')
```

however it has imported the data like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col5 | col7 | col8 | col9
     |      |      |      |      |      |      |      | data1\data2\data3\..
     |      |      |      |      |      |      |      | data1\data2\data3\..
     |      |      |      |      |      |      |      | data1\data2\data3..
...
```

it should look like:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9
data1|data2 |data3 |data4 |data5 |data6 |data7 |data8 |data9
data1|data2 |data3 |data4 |data5 |data6 |data7 |data8 |data9
...
```

I've tried changing the function to:

```
def import_csv(path):

    return pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-16', sep="\n")
```

but it makes no difference.

EDIT: I just did `list(df.columns)` and all columns came out as one list item, printed as: `['col1\col2\col3\col4\col5\col6\col7\col8\col9']`

Comment: impossible to answer without your sample data

Comment: Please add the csv data that you are reading

Comment: If you were to show example of your data it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: It's very difficult to send the CSV as it contains data I can't make public. It would take an awfully long time to change that data and there is a risk I will miss some.

Comment: How about you just copy the first 10 rows of the CSV and change the values just so we can see the structure. While you're at that try this: `pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-16', sep=",")`

Comment: I've put an example CSV here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EeQT5g0e-1LTB0ZfYSpocv4jfyW1Jxdi?usp=sharing with the first 10 rows. @letroot I tried `sep=","` but it didn't work.

Comment: Okay checking it out now.

Comment: Okay, so your CSV is separated by tabs and not commas. So specify the separator as `\t` like this `pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-16', sep="\t")` That ought to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV seems to be separated by tabs and not commas. Specify the separator as `\t` like this `pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-16', sep="\t")`. That ought to work.